# Unable to fetch cluster name and ASG resource name using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm quite new to using CDK, and I'm trying to generate user_data for my launch config. Having problems however... Took the userdata from here and trying to adapt that to my CDK template: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html#quickref-ecs-example-1.yaml

This is my code

```
     const asg = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ASG', {
            vpc: existingVpc,
            instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3, ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE),
            machineImage: ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
            minCapacity: 3,
            desiredCapacity: 3,
            maxCapacity: 10,
            instanceMonitoring: autoscaling.Monitoring.DETAILED,
        });

        // Create an ECS cluster
        const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'Cluster', {
            vpc: existingVpc,
            clusterName: envName,
        });

        asg.addUserData(`
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${cluster.clusterName} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${this.stackName} --resource ${asg} --region ${this.region}
`
        )
```

This generates the following user data

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - |-
                #!/bin/bash

                echo ECS_CLUSTER=
              - Ref: ClusterEB0386A7
              - |2
                 >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
                yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack CdkClusterStack --resource CdkClusterStack/ASG --region eu-west-1
```

This is very confusing to me. The `cluster.clusterName` does not return the cluster name at all, but a Ref to the underlying cluster resource.

For the ASG the following is generated, and I guess here instead of `CdkClusterStack/ASG` which I'm currently getting I would need `ASG46ED3070`

```
 ASG46ED3070:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      MaxSize: "10"
      MinSize: "3"
      DesiredCapacity: "3"
      .... more stuff ....
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

The Ref of the logical ID on ECS cluster returns the resource name which in this case is the cluster name.`When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the resource name.` This is from the [Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html) pages.

To check this, I would add the cluster.clusterName as a cfnOutput and check if it is giving you the actual cluster name infact.